# Parent-Child mapping with Fluent NHibernate does not insert children

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to map a very basic parent-child relation with Fluent NHibernate.
However, when analyzing the SQL, only the parent-INSERT statement is created.

The situation is a simple class with a list of other classes. No relation back to the parent is needed. The children needs to be inserted/updated when the parent is inserted/updated.

> ```
>         var room = new Room();
>         room.Name = "Room1";
>         room.Courses.Add(new Course(){ Name = "Course1"});
>         room.Courses.Add(new Course(){ Name = "Course2"});
>
>         using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
>         {
>             using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
>             {
>                 session.Insert(room);
>                 transaction.Commit();
>             }
>         }
> ```

The mapping looks like this.

> ```
> public class RoomMapping : ClassMap<Room>
> {
>     public RoomMapping()
>     {
>         Table("Rooms");
>
>         Id(x => x.Id)
>             .GeneratedBy.SeqHiLo("seq_rooms", "1000");
>
>         Map(x => x.Name);
>
>         HasMany(x => x.Courses)
>             .Cascade.All();
>     }
> }
>
> public class CourseMap : ClassMap<Course>
> {
>     public CourseMap()
>     {
>         Table("Courses");
>
>         Id(x => x.Id)
>             .GeneratedBy.SeqHiLo("seq_courses", "1000");
>
>         Map(x => x.Name);
>     }
> }
> ```

I already played with multiple options of the HasMany, however non with any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry people. I just found it out.
I'm working in a Stateless session. So no relationships are managed ;)